# Calculate possible sets of outcomes in a series of events.

Tags: probability

If there are 10 teams in a tournament,
and each team competes again each other team one time,
and possible outcomes of a match is either WIN, TIE, or LOSS for a particular team:

How many possible paths can the tournament take?

---

Eg:

Given 4 teams named "A", "B", "C", and "D".

There would be following matches in the tournament:

1. A vs B
2. C vs D
3. A vs C
4. B vs D
5. A vs D
6. B vs C

Possible "Paths":

1. "A vs B = A Win. C vs D = C Win. A vs C = A Win. B vs D = B Win. A vs D = A Win. B vs C = B Win."
2. "A vs B = A Win. C vs D = C Win. A vs C = A Win. B vs D = B Win. A vs D = A Win. B vs C = Tie."
3. "A vs B = A Win. C vs D = C Win. A vs C = A Win. B vs D = B Win. A vs D = A Win. B vs C = C Win."

...

So on and so forth with every possible outcome of every match.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With n teams, are $\dfrac{n^2-n}{2}$ matchs

Each match can end in victory for home team, tie or loss for home team (3 different outcomes).

Then, the number of paths are $3^{\dfrac{n^2-n}{2}}$

With $n = 10$ there are $3^{\dfrac{10^2-10}{2}} = 3^{45}$

Answer (score 0):

From your examples I think we could define two "paths" $p, p'$ to be distinct whenever there is at least one game such that in $p$ the outcome of the game is different than in $p'$. This makes the question rather easy as there are $3$ possible outcomes for every game and $6$ games. Thus the answer would be $3^6$.